# Run Angular Material docs locally

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to create my own UI library branded for my company for our projects. I would like to try to fork Angular Material to edit the components to my needs and change most of the CSS styles.

I also would like to create a docs platform (like https://material.angular.io/). Is there a repo with the source code of this website ? How can I clone this website and customize it ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The whole src code is on the github, for example component related stuff is under src/components-examples. Personally I would avoid it, I would suggest you use something like storybook. Good luck

Comment: I'd strongly advise not forking the components. You won't get any future updates. [Here](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) is the official guide on customizing Angular Material components.

Comment: Actually, you should probably start by [theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), then customize individual components (if needed) via the link above.